# FIPS security and Master password in Firefox not working in 57 (Ubunutu 17.10)

Tags: firefox, security, 17.10

After upgrading to Firefox 57 I now receive this message when trying to enable FIPS Security:

[image: FIPS not working]

Exiting and restarting the application does not fix the issue.

Any help with this appreciated.

**EDIT**: There is a problem with the Master Password now, the master password does not load when I start Firefox even after a restart. Previously the master password was required when Firefox starts up (a few seconds delay allowing for a web page to be loaded, unlike FIPS that prevents site loading before password is input) but now it seems to ask for the master password sometimes when logging into a new site. It seems like security settings in Firefox 57 do not work.

I tried reinstalling the program after a `sudo apt purge firefox` and deleting the `~/.mozilla` file but nothing seems to correct the issue.

Comment: You may have a look if there are more mozilla names folders in your home directory. For example `~/.local/share/mozilla` or `~/.config/mozilla`. Also I wonder do you really need FIPS-140-2 mode?

Comment: I deleted `~/.local` and `~/.config` files too  and still got the same issue. FIPS is a good protection against all kind of breaches in security. You should be using it @Videonauth

Comment: Well I spent now about 12 hours of research into this one and slowly I think this is a bug with Firefox 57.

Comment: Thanks for looking into is @Videonauth . I think it is an issue with Firefox 57... suspicious that it is not working properly. I think they're working on a fix for it as I have flagged the issue with Modzilla.

Comment: Yes me too, just alone I wrote half a roman as answer before figuring out that it ends simply up in the same situation as you are in right now.